# Select a table and create a table with the data similar to selected table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I wanted to create a table with a data similar to the table i have selected. My code below works but it only create the table with its column but there is no datas inserted

**Php Code**

```
if(isset($_POST['select_table']))
{
    //$select_db = $_POST['select_db'];
    $select_table = $_POST['select_table'];
    $db = mysql_select_db('section_masterfile',$connectDatabase);
    $query_select = "Create Table pdf_table AS (SELECT * FROM $select_table)";
    $create_query = mysql_query($query_select,$connectDatabase);
}
```

Comment: I think this is helpful `CREATE TABLE pdf_table LIKE select_table`

Comment: @Jeff . . . `create table as` should create the table and insert data.  Perhaps something else is wrong with your process.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it only create table with the column but not does not have data's inside it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks a lot i just dont have data's from the table i selected that is why i dont have any data also in my created table...Again Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this query:

```
CREATE TABLE pdf_table LIKE $select_table;
INSERT pdf_table SELECT * FROM $select_table;
```

[source](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1487/copy-an-existing-mysql-table-to-a-new-table/)

Comment: Thanks a lot all of you who comment in this post i just dont have a data inside one table and that is why i dont have any in the table i created

Answer (score 0):

Use this its working :

**CREATE TABLE table_name SELECT * FROM old_table;**

here **table_name** is new table name and **old_table** is the table that already in the database.